# Why doesn't the list item hold the reference to the variable in Dart in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

Say I have some `bool` autovalidate variables:

```
  bool _autoValidateEmail = false;
  bool _autoValidateCompanyName = false;
  bool _autoValidatePhoneNo = false;
  bool _autoValidateName = false;
  bool _autoValidateSurname = false;
```

then I want to put them in a List. I do that in initState():

```
autoValidateList.addAll([
      _autoValidateEmail,
      _autoValidateCompanyName,
      _autoValidatePhoneNo,
      _autoValidateName,
      _autoValidateSurname
    ]);
```

In runtime values get changes like so e.g.

```
setState(() {
            autoValidateList[0] = false;
          });
```

But then if I set the value for the `TextFormField` like so `autovalidate: _autoValidateEmail,` it does not get updated. However, if I set it like this: `autovalidate: autoValidateList[1],` it works fine.

So why is the referenced value in the list doesn't get updated in the widget tree? When set directly => `autovalidate: _autoValidateEmail,`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything in Dart is an `Object`, and all variables are essentially references to `Object`s.  When you do:

```
var myList = [variable1, variable2, variable3];
```

you're creating a `List` that references a bunch of `Object`s.  Your `List` does *not* have references to `variable1`, `variable2`, etc.

That is, you have:

```
variable1 ----> object1 <---- myList[0]
variable2 ----> object2 <---- myList[1]
variable3 ----> object3 <---- myList[2]
```

(Note that none of this actually has anything to do with `List`.  If you did:

```
var variable2 = variable1;
```

You'd have the same behavior: reassigning `variable2` does not change what `variable1` refers to.)

When you set `myList[0] = somethingElse`, you'll end up with:

```
variable1 ----> object1       myList[0] ----> somethingElse
variable2 ----> object2 <---- myList[1]
variable3 ----> object3 <---- myList[2]
```

You can't make assignments to `myList[0]` change the assignment of `variable1`.  You can, however, make `variable1` and `myList[0]` refer the same `Object` that you can *mutate*.  For example:

```
class Wrapper<T> {
  Wrapper(this.value);
  T value;
}

final variable1 = Wrapper<bool>(true);
final myList = [variable1, ...];
```

Now if you do `myList[0].value = false`, `variable1.value` will be `false` as well.

Comment: You said everything is an Object, so `bool variable1` is an Object, so when creating a List, why doesn't it take the reference to this object? But once you wrap it, then you can have a reference to that object. What part does the wrapping play here?

Comment: @Mantoska It *does* create a reference to the `bool` `Object`.  However, `bool` objects aren't *mutable*.  Assigning a variable just changes what that variable refers to; it does *not* mutate the underlying data.

Answer (score 1):

That is because those booleans are in different parts of the memory. Changing one on the list doesn't change the ones declared at the top. When you create the list, a copy of each bool is made, living in a different place in memory.